# How do I get started with image processing?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

I am really interested in image processing. I downloaded OpenCV and started playing with it. But I think I lack the knowledge behind image processing. I would like to learn the basic fundamentals of image processing.

I searched for open course from MIT or other universities but didn't seem to find any good tutorial. I did find some slides, but they seem useless without the actually presentation. I searched for online tutorial but mostly they are not for beginners.

Is there a good online tutorial for image processing for beginners?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend two books:

(1) R. C. Gonzalez and R. E. Woods, [Digital Image Processing, 3rd ed.](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN013168728X) Prentice Hall, Aug. 2007.

(2) G. Bradski and A. Kaehler, [Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library, 1st ed.](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0596516134) O'Reilly Media, Oct. 2008.

Visit the [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/) to get updated reference to the OpenCV functions (the Learning OpenCV book uses version 1.0 but the current version is 2.3). You can buy cheap access to the digital version of the book using [Safari Books](http://safaribooksonline.com/Corporate/Index/).

Comment: The Gonzales Woods book is what I had for some of my Computer Vision / Image Processing classes. It is quite good if I remember correctly.

Comment: I do NOT recommend (2) because it teaches old style OpenCV that will get you nowhere given the current version of OpenCV. Gonzales is definitely what you should read.

Answer (score 3):

I really like Rich Szeliski's Computer Vision [book](http://szeliski.org/Book/) which has a nice mix of theory and practice. You can also access the electronic drafts for free.

Other good ones are Hartley and Zissermann's [Multi-View Projective Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518) and David Forsyth's [Computer Vision: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130851981)

Comment: Hartley and Zissermann's is *not* an introductory book.

Comment: Not only are Hartley and Zissermann's NOT an introductory book, Forsyth's book is NOT about image processing.

Comment: The Szeliski book looks like a nice complement to Gonzalez and Woods. I'd heard of it before, but hadn't peruse it. Thanks! It's quite nice that the author posted the PDF online.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the old fashioned way is best.  I'd start by looking at what [books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=image+processing&x=0&y=0) could help me learn the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Reading books is IMO definitely the way to go here.

The [Learning OpenCV](http://books.google.com/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book also contains background information about the image processing tasks that can be executed with OpenCV. It might be a nice way of learning to immediately put in practice what you learn and read.

Comment: The Learning OpenCV book is good but the syntax of the library has moved on slightly (especially in c++) so the examples require a bit of work. There is a project to update the examples and put out a 2ed

Comment: The book is a nice introduction to some theory combined to hands-on using OpenCV. But, as pointed by @Martin Beckett, the book uses OpenCV 1.0 and the current version of the library is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenCV Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FullOpenCVWiki) actually lists a few books they recomend, including one from O'Riley which I have always found to be a good source for learning.

Comment: I live the OpenCV O'Reilly for learning OpenCV and I have a copy.  I don't think it's great for learning image processing.

Answer (score 1):

[Alan Peters](http://www.vuse.vanderbilt.edu/~rap2/AlsMainPage.html) Lectures on Image Processing

http://www.archive.org/details/Lectures_on_Image_Processing

PDF files: http://ia700307.us.archive.org/7/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/

--

MIT OCW: [Biomedical Signal and Image Processing](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-582j-biomedical-signal-and-image-processing-spring-2007/)

Answer (score 1):

See [page](http://www.tmorley.net/beginner-ip-tutorials)

This site has tutorials in pdf format explaining how to do basic image processing with Microsoft C# (which is free of charge from Microsoft).

It also introduces and explains the mathematical notation that you will find in image processing books.